# How to test Firebase JobDispatcher Job(Which is run daily)

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler, firebase-job-dispatcher

I had created job run every day.

```
    Driver driver = new GooglePlayDriver(this);
    FirebaseJobDispatcher firebaseJobDispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(driver);

    final int periodicity = (int) TimeUnit.DAYS.toSeconds(1);
    final int toleranceInterval = (int) TimeUnit.HOURS.toSeconds(1);

    Job chatBackupJob = firebaseJobDispatcher.newJobBuilder()
            .setService(MyJobService.class)
            .setTag(MyJobService.SERVICE_TAG)
            .setConstraints(Constraint.ON_ANY_NETWORK)
            .setLifetime(Lifetime.FOREVER)
            .setRecurring(true)
            .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(periodicity, periodicity + toleranceInterval))
            .setReplaceCurrent(false)
            .setRetryStrategy(RetryStrategy.DEFAULT_EXPONENTIAL)
            .build();
    firebaseJobDispatcher.mustSchedule(chatBackupJob);
```

How can I test this code? 
I want to test same as AlarmManager, If we change time in alarm manager is triggered, but JobScheduler is not triggered.
I wanted to make sure from my side is this job call every day(or given time interval)?
Please give me some suggestion